# Changing variable value after method call

Tags: python

Let's say I have a method m1, which has variables x and y. I am calling method m2 from m1 multiple times. And every time I call m2 the values of the local variables of m1, x and y need to change (say increment / decrement). How can I avoid the repeating statements after the method call?

```
def m2():
    #action
    pass

def m1():
    x = 0
    y = 0

    #call to m2 followed by changes in local variable
    m2()
    x += 1
    y -= 1

    #next call to m2 followed by changes in local variable
    #is there a way to avoid the repetition?
    m2()
    x += 1
    y -= 1

    #...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a function in `m1` that does the job for you

```
def m1():
    x = 0
    y = 0

    def _m2():
        m2()
        nonlocal x
        nonlocal y
        x += 1
        y -= 1

    _m2()
    _m2()

    # the value of x and y are 2 and -2 now
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :) This works in python 3 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a new wrapper like function:

```
def call_m2(x,y):
    m2()
    return x+1, y-1
```

and then set your function calls to be:

```
x, y = call_m2(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, however, m2 is already returning some values. So call_m2 will have to combine all the return parameters. I was thinking of avoiding this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how `x` and `y` are changing beforehand (say, x takes all values from 1 through 10 while y is equal to `2x+4`), then consider using lists. This has the advantage of also saving you the effort to manually type all the calls to `m2()`

```
xlist = ['list', 'of', 'all', 'x-values']
ylist = ['list', 'of', 'all', 'y-values']
for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
    m2()
```

If the values of `x` and `y` depend on the outcome of `m2()`, you could implement a `while`-loop with some sort of stop condition and update the values of `x` and `y` at the end of each loop iteration

Comment: Thanks. It's just simple arithmetic  in my case. So maybe this would complicate the things a bit.